# Why use the non-exclusive or sign in equations?

Tags: logic, notation, diophantine-equations

$x^2=4 \Leftrightarrow x = 2 \lor x=-2$, but $x$ can't be equal to both $2$ and $-2$, unlike what the inclusive-or symbol ($\lor$) implies. Although it may seem obvious, it's just wrong to say that $x$ has both values.

I always thought of this as a strange convention. Where does it come from? Why is it used today? Why not use an [exclusive disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) symbol, such as "$\oplus$" (although in equations this "$\oplus$" symbol is prone to be confused with self-defined operators, there are many others)?

### Edit:

I was starting to doubt the validity of my arguments, so I tried to formalize them  little more. Here's the result (still, I'm not very convinced of my own argument):

Remember $a\lor b=(a\land b)\oplus(a\land \lnot b)\oplus(\lnot a\land b)$ as shown by the following:
$$
0\lor 0=(0\land 0)\oplus(0\land \lnot 0)\oplus(\lnot 0\land 0) = 0\\
0\lor 1=(0\land 1)\oplus(0\land \lnot 1)\oplus(\lnot 0\land 1) = 1\\
1\lor 0=(1\land 0)\oplus(1\land \lnot 0)\oplus(\lnot 1\land 0) =1\\
1\lor 1=(1\land 1)\oplus(1\land \lnot 1)\oplus(\lnot 1\land 1)=1\\
$$

While $a\oplus b=(a\land \lnot b)\oplus(\lnot a\land b)$
$$
0\oplus 0=(0\land \lnot 0)\oplus(\lnot 0\land 0)=0\\
0\oplus 1=(0\land \lnot 1)\oplus(\lnot 0\land 1)= 1\\
1\oplus 0=(1\land \lnot 0)\oplus(\lnot 1\land 0)=1\\
1\oplus 1=(1\land \lnot 1)\oplus(\lnot 1\land 1)=0\\
$$

Now take $a = P(\{x=2\})$ and $b = P(\{x=-2\})$ where $x^2=4$ and $P$ is the [predicate function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)).

Now let's say they're both true at the same time $(1;1)$ (which should be false, as a number can only have one value), and test whether that is valid according to inclusive-or: it turns out it is, $1\lor 1=1$! But that is ridiculous, $a\land b$ should not be considered even as a mere option, $P(\{x=2\})$ and $P(\{x=-2\})$ (the values of our predicates, $a$ and $b$) are mutually exclusive!

In fact, if we were talking about the corresponding predicates of $\pm 0$, however; as I admited (I haven't thought of it until @Asaf Karagila considered it; and would've never considered what @Trevor Wilson [said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480890/why-use-the-non-exclusive-or-sign-in-equations#comment-1036269)), it was possible, and in fact a necessary option, that $a\land b$. Anyway, in those cases, simple ol' plain inclusive disjunction should be used.

Comment: Because we know $-2\neq 2$, we don't really care that it is written as non-exclusive "or." The symbol $\oplus$ is also confusing - it doesn't "feel" like "exclusive or" to me, even though it is a pretty common notation (at least when dealing with sets. I haven't seen it used in propositional logic that often.)

Comment: @Thomas, as I said, I don't like the notation (it was the only one I knew in LaTeX - replace it by one you prefer in the link to Wikipedia).

Comment: But what if $2$ _is_ equal to $-2$, as in the case of a field of characteristic $2$?

Comment: @Trevor, I really don't know what you mean, but as with $0$ in the real numbers, one'd use $\lor$.

Comment: My point was that it might be considered desirable to write something that generalizes better (Asaf and myself mentioned two different ways in which writing $\vee$ here generalizes better.)

Comment: Another point would be: The way the equivalence is written, to check the $\Leftarrow$ direction one only has to check that $(-2)^2 = 4$ and $2^2=4$. The extra information that "$x = -2$" and "$x = 2$" are mutually exclusive (in the case of the real numbers) does not help to prove that $x^2=4$, so why record it?

Answer (score 10):

Because (a) we don't care about this sort of redundancy; and (b) generally $x^2=y^2\iff y=x\lor x=-y$, replacing this with an exclusive or is false for $x=y=0$.

Comment: @JMCF125: Because exclusive or means that exactly one of the following are true: $x=0$, $x=-0$. However *both* are true because $0=-0$, and therefore the statement $x^2=0\iff x=0\oplus x=-0$ is false.

Comment: You're right, I was wrong. But perhaps zero can get a special treatment here, as it gets in division. When we know they can both be zero, we use $\lor$.

Comment: Having a slightly redundant, but very readable and concise statement is vastly better than a by-cases statement.

Comment: Is a dot over the symbol going to kill readability?

Comment: No, but "If $x\neq 0$ then ... and it $x=0$ then ..." is not nearly as clear as the "redundant" phrasing. But go ahead, write however you see fit. When you'll do enough mathematics, you'll realize what is important and what's less important, and what's bothering more or less.

Answer (score 3):

I'll write an answer to emphasise something. Inclusive "or" do not *imply* that both disjuncts may be true. It only *allows* it. To say it even more clearly: it does *not exclude* this possibility.

So one can't say that it is wrong or incorrect to write as in the example: it is just less precise (exclusive "or" would explicitly say that both disjuncts can't be true). As said in the last comment of Asaf Karagila in mathematics we don't try to be 100% precise all the time - it is often enough to have a bound instead of the exact value or the limit instead of the whole function. We just don't waste our attention to care (or write) about unnecessary details (unnecessary at the moment, because it may of course depend on what we are trying to do). It's some kind of abstraction - which is known to be fundamental for mathematics.

**Edit** (to reflect update of the question):

Why do you care so much about an impossible scenario? If you assume that $2=-2$, then you can prove anything and $x=2=-2$ is no more ridiculous than $2\neq -2$ (or whatever). Note also the law of excluded middle is formulated as $p\lor \neg p$, which - if I understand correctly - is unacceptable from your point of view.

Comment: As I'm not talking about any modal logic, _allowing_ it and _implying_ it are for all purposes the same. I'll edit the question to make myself clearer.

Comment: @JMCF125 Sorry, I don't get how *do not exclude* (because I'm just too lazy to do it) is the same as *imply*. If I didn't exclude $1=0$, it doesn't mean that I claimed it is true. It just means that I didn't bother to negate it.

Comment: In $\Bbb F_2$, $2=-2$. Remember that in the language of fields we write $2$ as an abbreviation for $1+1$ and $-2$ as the unique element which the additive inverse of $1+1$. In $\Bbb F_2$, $1+1=0$ and so $2=-2$. So it's not so impossible after all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I know, but I supposed that the context is clear here and I don't need such restrictions.

Comment: Yes, I do reject the original law of the excluded middle (as said in the respective page of Wikipedia, "Other systems reject the law entirely."). Notice our "or" in normal day-to-day conversation is the **exclusive**, not the **inclusive** or (this one is usually represented in non-mathematical/non-philosophical texts as **and/or**). I see it as $\forall p, p\oplus \lnot p$.

Comment: «and $x=2=−2$ is no more ridiculous than $2≠−2$»: yes it is, the first is false; the second is true.

Comment: @JMCF125 Ad 2. Under the assumptions the first is true;)$$\ $$
Ad 1. "and/or" is ugly. In Polish we have two distinct words for exclusive and inclusive "or" - the distinction is mainly known to lawers and mathematicians, but other people also often use them "correctly".
Btw. how do you express inclusive "or" with your day-to-day exclusive "or"? "only A or only B or both"...? I really prefer my inclusive "or";)

Comment: How do I express it? With "and/or" (actually, with it's equivalent in Portuguese "e/ou", I'm not an English native speaker): "A and/or B" If you notice, although it sounds bad, it makes sense, as $\forall a\forall b,a\lor b=(a\land b)\oplus (a\oplus b)$. I wish there were two "ors" in my language (and wonder whether there are any in Esperanto). Also, your updated answer sounds better, so I gave it one upvote.